# Onenote Macro to remove spaces between screen clippings

Tags: macros, onenote

I need a macro to remove the spaces between the screen clippings,
I have downloaded the onetastic macro to resize images and remove spaces. But that does not working. The image resize part is working, but it is not removing the spaces between the screen clippings. I tried to modify and make it work. I could not do it.  Please help
Please find the macro code below,[image: Screeshot of the Macro]

Answer (score 0):

you should go to http://www.omeratay.com/onetastic/ and you can find the support for that add-in there.

Comment: yes, done that. But no response from the author of that macro